# Calculating nodes in tree

Tags: c#

I have a Balanced tree and a number. I need to count the number of tree nodes with the specified value of information fields.I need call method in one class, but in another.
Method for going through tree.

```
public void Treetment(TNode root, int info, int x)
    {
        if (root != null)
        {
            if (root.Info == info)
            {
                x++;
            }
            Treetment(root.Left, info, x);
            Treetment(root.Right, info, x);
        }

    }
```

Method on a button to call the method upper.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x = 0;
        Menu main = Owner as Menu;
        int info = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        main.Tree.Treetment(main.Tree.Root, info, x);
        textBox2.Text = x.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: What does "I need call method in one class, but in another" mean?

Comment: I need to call the method in the class, clicking on button in winForm. The class, which includes the method, is not the code of win Form

Comment: Note that `Treetment` has no return value. `x` is a value parameter and changing `x` does nothing on the calling side. What is wrong with your code as shown besides that?

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with trees it is usually convenient to have a method that flattens the tree. I.e. iterates over the tree and returns each and every node. You can do this using a iterator block like this:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> DepthFirstIterator<T>(this T root, Func<T, (T, T)> getChildren) 
    {
        var stack = new Stack<T>();
        stack.Push(root);
        T left, right;
        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            var current = stack.Pop();                
            do
            {
                yield return current;
                (left, right) = getChildren(current);
                if (right != null)
                {
                    stack.Push(right);
                }
            }
            while ((current = left) != null);
        }
    }
```

This uses a generic type and a delegate to help get the children of a node. But it should be fairly easy to adapt to use a fixed type, or a generic type with a interface constraint. Once you have a iterator of all nodes you can simply use LINQ to count or filter the nodes. Something like this:

```
public class TreeNode
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public TreeNode Left { get; }
    public TreeNode Right { get; }
    public TreeNode(int id, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) => (Id, Left, Right) = (id, left, right);
}


var root = new TreeNode(1,
    new TreeNode(2, new TreeNode(3, null, null), null),
    new TreeNode(4, null, null));
var allNodes = root.DepthFirstIterator(f => (f.Left, f.Right)).Count(t => t.Id % 2 == 0);
```